# How do I output this table without getting an empty message error?

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to create a discord bot that allows the command '!prem' to display the current Premier League table. (The program which scrapes the table is not mine - https://pastebin.com/Mut7C4Nv) However I have changed it a bit so it is in a function I can access from another file - https://pastebin.com/fB4fB4ia

However, whenever I type the command into discord, it prints the table into my terminal but instead of messaging it to discord, I get the error '400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send empty message'.

Here is the file in which the command is setup: https://pastebin.com/NkFZmnTV

```
import random
import premier_league
 
 
 
def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
 
    if p_message == '!hello':
        return 'Hey there!'
 
    if message == '!roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))
 
    if p_message == '!help':
        return "`Make sure all commands start with a '!''. If you want to see a list of commands type '!commands'.`"
    
    if p_message == '!prem':
        table_output = premier_league.get_premier_league_table()
        return table_output 
    
 
    return "I didn't understand what you wrote. Try typing '!help'."
```

Sorry if I've done any stupid errors, I'm relatively new to this.

I've tried to change the way the table is displayed using return and print, however as I said before, I'm relatively new and am not sure what to try.

I even pasted all of the code for the prem table into the responses file under where the command is setup but I got the same issue - '400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send empty message'

Comment: Could you print the `table_output` and include the output in the question? From glancing at your `pastebin` links, I don't see any anomalies. If the `discord.py` throws an error saying `i can send an empty string` that's pretty much is what's going on. Somehow `table_output` is empty.

Comment: @doneforaiur https://gyazo.com/2b31a34d4fad60557118e2582b76d3bc

Comment: It seems strange that there is `None` at the end of the output. Could you just delete `print` statement and run the code again?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0cc50aff8f1e56cfe1a40c0bcee237da
Yeah the `none` disappears

Comment: Welp, that's your answer right there. `get_premier_league_table()` doesn't return any data, it just prints it. It should return some `string`. Instead of `print`ing `rank, games_won` at every `row`, you should add them to a single list and then return them after de `for` loop.